# How to get the JSON from collection using find().fetch() in meteor if we have key as variable

Tags: json, meteor, collections

I need to get the json from collection used in meteor application using find().fetch() method by key. I have key as variable and also i have value as a variable , now i have to get the json from collection where key will be my key and value will be my value . Means i need to check both key and values with my obtained key and value. 
My code is :

```
enter code here'fetch_values':function(mykey,myvalue){var x=Mydatas.find({mykey:myvalue}).fetch();
      console.log(x);
           return x;}
```

I m using this code but it giving me empty array of JSON i.e. `[]` , SO please help me how can i get the json  using find() method.

Comment: "enter code here" This is nothing , it comes by mistake so please ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your query like this in javascript first so that the literal key value is set.

```
var query = {};    
query[mykey] = myvalue;

var x = Mydatas.find(query).fetch();
```

Comment: wow !!! , Its working!!!!!!! . You are really genius sir. Today , you helped me alot and you almost saved me. Ty again . :D

Comment: i have one more question , Do you know how to put lazy loading on datalist in meteor. I know that it done by infinte scrolling and i saw it in atmospherejs.com but i didn't get that example. Can u help me in this too? I also post question for it.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?